# How to create a copy-to-clipboard button in streamlit?

Tags: python, button, clipboard, streamlit

[This discussion](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/copy-dataframe-to-clipboard/2633/6) provides a workaround:

```py
import streamlit as st
from bokeh.models.widgets import Button
from bokeh.models import CustomJS
from streamlit_bokeh_events import streamlit_bokeh_events
import pandas as pd

text_to_be_copied = "Some text"
copy_dict = {"content": text_to_be_copied}

copy_button = Button(label="Copy Text")
copy_button.js_on_event("button_click", CustomJS(args=copy_dict, code="""
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(content);
    """))

no_event = streamlit_bokeh_events(
    copy_button,
    events="GET_TEXT",
    key="get_text",
    refresh_on_update=True,
    override_height=75,
    debounce_time=0)
```

However, the button looks different than the usual streamlit buttons and cannot be used like those for example like this:

```py
if st.button("Some button"):
    st.write("Some reaction")
```

Is there a way to modify the streamlit buttons such that they copy a text to the clipboard?

Answer (score 0):

You must use `pyperclip` library to achieve what you want.

```
import pyperclip
text_to_be_copied = 'The text to be copied to the clipboard.'
pyperclip.copy(text_to_be_copied)
```

Comment: Note that this will copy the text to the clipboard of the host system that is running streamlit, not to the clipboard of the user who is using streamlit in the browser (which is probably the scenario that most people are interested in).

Comment: This only works locally, that is if your app is deployed on your computer, ok, If you deploy the app on a remote server (cloud or other), it will eventually copy to the remote clipboard (eventually: if it's enabled on the system, which is neither likely not useful).

Comment: There are some use cases (albeit edge cases) where someone does want to make a desktop app from a streamlit app using something like stlite. In those cases the app is technically served on the users machine and then this can work.